External MySQL Master and a regularly called AWS slave is this possible?
I'm working for a client, we handle food related orders
We are having problem in our server during peak hours (5PM - 8PM) and we are evaluating proposition to scale this server.
We are trying to keep cost lows and scale horizontally more than vertically.
We have a On premise DB and server which we don't want to switch.
This is for a Web App in PHP7.3 and Laravel8 and MySQL.
We made some cleaning in the tables, partitioned the data, updated our indexes, cleaned our db and optimized our requests.
Currently we are ok, but the business is currently growing at a slow but steady pace.
I'm currently looking into the location of a server for handling a master slave architecture in MySQL
Limited by cost, having a second server up and running at all time might be a waste of ressources, since 75% of our orders (when the website is having troubles) is between 5pm - 8pm.
I was looking into the creation of a MySQL instance through AWS, which would boot, each day at 4PM, replicate/ update from the masters data then do is role as a Slave till 8 PM, which would then be killed.
I looked into creating a RDS MySQL instance, which can handle a read replica. With automating the instances with AWS lambda or AWS CloudWatch
Is this something possible or am i delusional ?
What are the caveats of this method ?
Thank you
